# IIS - Port Redirection - Rewrite Module - Web.Config File

Tags: iis, module, url-rewriting, web-config

I am attempting to create an appropriate web.config file to redirect end users with the intention of adding a port to the request.

Any end user that types in http://subscribe.service.com/lists/index.html for example would be redirected to http://subscribe.service.com:3000/lists/index.html so that regardless of the called request it would add into it :3000.

Code example that I am using is provided below. In validation testing it appears to work as I would want it to. In practice nothing is occurring when I got to the physical website.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="3000 Port Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="http:/(.*)com" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="\.com(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}:3000{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You really need to study IIS URL Rewrite carefully, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 starting from Mistake 1.

Answer (score 0):

As Lex Li's article mentioned, url rewrite model partern not match the domain. That means IIS use lists/index.html to match the "http:/(.*)com" rule. So you will find your rule is not working.

I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule.

```
  <rule name="rewrite to 81 port" enabled="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />

                <action type="Redirect" url=" http://subscribe.service.com:3000/{R:0}"  appendQueryString="true"/>
            </rule>
```

Then it will work well.